# Nested array transform with array without nesting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Сan someone help with the algorithm? I get an array with objects that has arrays and so on. and i want to make one array without nested elements
I can get unlimited number of nested array

```
const test = [
    {
    id: "1",
    title: "test1",
    description: "some text",
    child: [
        {
        id: "2",
        title: "test2",
        description: "some text2",
        child: [
          {
            id: "4",
            title: "test4",
            description: "some text4",
            child: [
              {
                id: "5",
                title: "test5",
                description: "some text5",
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        id: "3",
        title: "test3",
        description: "some text3",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I should get an array with element level
Should be something like this:

```
const order = [
    {
    id: "1",
    title: "test1",
    description: "some text",
    url: 'test1',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "test2",
    description: "some text2",
    url: 'test1/test2',
    level: 2
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    title: "test4",
    description: "some text4",
    url: 'test1/test2/test4',
    level: 3
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    title: "test5",
    description: "some text5",
    url: 'test1/test2/test4/test5',
    level: 4
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "test3",
    description: "some text3",
    url: 'test1/test3',
    level: 2
  }
]
```

Can someone help me please

Comment: Looks like a **pre-order traversal** that keeps track of the depth.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order,_NLR) that keeps track of the depth and path it took. Each time there are more children, we increase the depth and add the title of the child to the path.

```js
const data = [{id:"1",title:"test1",description:"some text",child:[{id:"2",title:"test2",description:"some text2",child:[{id:"4",title:"test4",description:"some text4",child:[{id:"5",title:"test5",description:"some text5"}]}]},{id:"3",title:"test3",description:"some text3"}]}];

function flatten(root, acc = [], depth = 1, path = []) {
    acc.push({
        id: root.id,
        title: root.title,
        description: root.description,
        url: path.concat(root.title).join("/"),
        level: depth,
    });
      
    if (root.child)
        root.child.forEach((c) => flatten(c, acc, depth + 1, path.concat(root.title)));
   
    return acc;
}

console.log(data.flatMap((e) => flatten(e)));
```

This function is meant for a single node, and since you have an array of them, I have used `flatMap` in case you add more nodes to `data`.

Answer (score 1):

let's write a simple function for this

```
function simplify (arr) {
let returnArr = [];

const recursive = (array, level) => {

    array.forEach((item, index) => {
       let arrayObj = {level: level};

       Object.keys(item).forEach((key, index) => {
          if(!Array.isArray(item[key])){
             arrayObj[key] = item[key];
          }else{
             recursive(item[key], level + 1)
          }
       })

       returnArr.push(arrayObj)
    })
 }
recursive(arr, 1)

return returnArr
}
```

this should do the trick, let me know if it worked for you   :)

Comment: this is not done lol it accidentally posted, 1min pls

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recusive approach with [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
const
    flat = (array = [], level = 1, u = '') => array.flatMap(({ child = [], ...item }) => {
        const url = u + (u && '/') + item.title;
        return [{ ...item, level, url }, ...flat(child, level + 1, url)]
    }),
    data = [{ id: "1", title: "test1", description: "some text", child: [{ id: "2", title: "test2", description: "some text2", child: [{ id: "4", title: "test4", description: "some text4", child: [{ id: "5", title: "test5", description: "some text5" }] }] }, { id: "3", title: "test3", description: "some text3" }] }],
    result = flat(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the `level` and `url` properties that OP wants, however.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to [recursively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) go through your object and iterate each child until your full array is built up.

Additionally, you'll need to keep track of several things along the way: the `level` (depth), the `url`, and your final return array. Often times for recursive functions, you have a "private" function that does the real work, and a small function that exposes a reduced API. In JS, you can use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to create a closure so this private method can't be accessed.

Here is my solution:

```js
const flattenObj = (() => {
  const _flattenObj = (obj, result, level, url) => {
    level++;

    // Only add a `/` if we have some length to our URL
    let currentUrl = url ? `${url}/${obj.title}` : obj.title;

    const newObj = {
      id: obj.id,
      title: obj.title,
      description: obj.description,
      url: currentUrl,
      level,
    };

    // Add the new object to our return array, which maintains the same reference
    result.push(newObj);

    if (obj.child) {
      // Recursively iterate the children if they exist
      for (let child of obj.child) {
        _flattenObj(child, result, level, currentUrl);
      }
    }

    // Finally, return our full array
    return result;
  };

  // The real function we'll be calling, which initializes the extra arguments
  return obj => {
    return _flattenObj(obj, [], 0, '');
  };
})();

console.log(
  flattenObj({
    id: '1',
    title: 'test1',
    description: 'some text',
    child: [
      {
        id: '2',
        title: 'test2',
        description: 'some text2',
        child: [
          {
            id: '4',
            title: 'test4',
            description: 'some text4',
            child: [
              {
                id: '5',
                title: 'test5',
                description: 'some text5',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        title: 'test3',
        description: 'some text3',
      },
    ],
  })
);
```

Comment: You don't need an IIFE to create the closure. A closure will be created when you call the function. Just `return _flattenObj(...)`. No need for an IIFE and returning a function.

Comment: The whole point is to not expose the `_flattenObj()` method to the end user. They can only interact with `flattenObj()` because the implementation details of the last 3 args `result, level, url` should be opaque. Otherwise, sure, you don't need the IIFE. Its just to make that part of the API "private."

Comment: Sorry, it's a little hard to explain with words. I've edited your code to demonstrate what I meant: https://tsplay.dev/NdrdvW. There is no need for an IIFE.

Comment: The downside to that is we are creating the `_flattenObj` function _every time_, as opposed to once in the IIFE. All of that works, of course. It mostly comes down to preference if you find the IIFE hard to read, or see a performance hit by recreating `_flattenObj` each time.